# Multisubject Pages in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following pages

```
http://example.com/color/red 
http://example.com/car/escort
```

In ASP.NET Webform, I can use URL Rewrite to rewrite both pages so that the rule rewrites the pages to

```
http://example.com/process.aspx?subject=color&type={1}
http://example.com/process.aspx?subject=car&type={1}
```

and then Process.aspx does all the work.

Is there a way I can emulate the above in MVC without using IIS Rewrite?  Is this handled in MVC routing or somewhere else, do I need IIS Rewrite to help me?

Comment: I think I understand your question. My question, Why do not use the QueryString method? If you want to use or even parameters?

Comment: I'd like the SEO method style of the color/red style rather than doing second method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MVC routing. Assuming that http://example.com/ will invoke the index method on the Home controller. You can add before your default MapRoute

```
routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "RouteWithColor",
                    url: "Color/{Color}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
                );

   routes.MapRoute(
    name: "RouteWithCar",
    url: "car/{car}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
         );
```

Then In your controller

> ```
>         var car = RouteData.Values["Car"];
>         var color = RouteData.Values["Color"];
> ```
>
> With this if the user navigate to the page using http://example.com/Car/somecare you will have the value it your variable. So you can check if your variables are null and continue your treatement

Comment: I tried to implement that with

                routes.MapRoute(
                name: "star",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { Controller = "star", action = "Index", id=UrlParameter.Optional }
                );

but when I do localhost/star/sirius , it returns 404 error.  I did try the methods Oussama_gd suggested.  If i do localhost/star , it begins the debugger.  Sorry for the formatting.

Comment: If I set the MapRoute to :- routes.MapRoute( "", "star/{sstar}", new { Controller = "star", id = UrlParameter.Optional });    then to get it to work, the url is localhost/star/index/sirius which is definately not what I want.  I don't want index to appear in the URL.  How can I remove the index from the URL ?